# how to use in Reactjs functional component history.push

Tags: reactjs, push, history

I have a functional component that has form. Onsubmit call I would like to redirect to another page.

```
function ProfileForm(props) {
 // many code removed
 const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
   e.target.reset();
   history.push({
  pathname:  "/OnSubmit",
  state: {
    response: messageFromServer 
   } 
  }
}
// many code removed
}
```

I got this erro:-

> Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals

After Googling the error I found a similar kind of answer for location. Answer was: 
`Try adding window before location (i.e. window.location).`
So I tried:-

```
  window.history.push({
  pathname:  "/OnSubmit",
  state: {
    response: messageFromServer 
  } 
}
```

got new error:-

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): window.history.push is not a function

Comment: Try [window.history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you handle routing with `react-router`. If so, you need to use the history object which is passed through the `ReactRouterContext`.
To do that, you need to use `useHistory` hook to get the `history` object.

```js
// ...
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
// ...


function ProfileForm(props) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
     e.target.reset();
     history.push({
        pathname:  "/OnSubmit",
        state: {
          response: messageFromServer 
        } 
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, it works. But there is another problem. Before  this call I make a post request as:  `axios.post('http://localhost:8080/profile', profile)
      .then(res => {
        setMessageFromServer(res.data)
      }).catch((error) => {
        // handle this error
        setMessageFromServer(error.data)
      })` I would like to get this response and send to the OnSubmit page. How can i wait for this response?

Comment: It's a little bit hard to recommend something without knowing your routing and state management architecture. You can lift the state to the first mutual parent of `ProfileForm` and `OnSubmitPage`, pass a callback prop to `ProfileForm` called `onSuccess`, and use it like, `axios.post('http://localhost:8080/profile', profile).then(res => { onSuccess(res.data); history.push("/onSubmit"); })...`. Then, the mutual parent can pass this state to `OnSubmitPage`.

Comment: If you are using `redux` or `mobx`, that's a whole another story and lots of different solutions. You can use `contextAPI`. You can even simply write the data so `sessionStorage`, redirect to `OnSubmitPage` and read the value from the storage. It al depends on your architecture.

Comment: Handling API responses is a big topic in React. There are simple ways, advanced ways and "hardly maintainable" ways. You can use `redux` or `mobx` but some of the community is recently running away from them because of the complexity and their negative impacts. There are also people trying to separate the UI state from the API state. They say that the UI state like `isDarkTheme`, `isDrawerOpen` should be stored to a separate store from the which holds the responses of an API (this simply becomes a cache). You can check `swr` and `react-query` too. Like I said. Lots  of alternatives.

Comment: I'm not using redux or mobx. I just need to wait until I get response from the server. I will try to follow ur callback solution.

Comment: Thanks that call back worked fine. How do I prevent the user to go back after he submitted? I meant when he is on OnSubmit page, he can't go back to ProfileForm or even if he goes back there won't be any old data. It should be an empty form.

Comment: if you are using react-router-dom v5, then you should import from react-router-dom: import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `history.push` try to use navigate

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const addToCartHandler = () => {
  navigate(`/cart/${productId}?qty=${qty}`)
};
```

Comment: Nowadays this should be the accepted answer. useNavigate is a more recent hook and it makes your code more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

**Use props.history Instead**

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
   e.target.reset();
   props.history.push("/OnSubmit")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useHistory(). The follwoing code can help you.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

export default function Checkout(props) {
    
const history = useHistory();
 
return (
              <React.Fragment>
                <AddressForm history ={ history} ></AddressForm>
              </React.Fragment>
        </Paper>
      </main>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```