# How to redirect user from login page to another react page if the login was successful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router-dom

- Hey, I'm working on my first full-stack application using React for front-end + Node, Express for back-end.
- I have a /login route (using: react router dom). I want user to log in with email and password then do a fetch request (POST) to my server to compare these data with the data stored in my database. I managed to do all of that but I wanna know HOW REDIRECT THE USER FROM /login TO /DASHBOARD page(component) if the user account is registered in the database. How to do that redirection ?
  I saw tutorial but he was using ejs and made a redirect on the server. How to do that but instead of redirecting to ejs page, redirect user to another react component/page ???
- My project structure: client folder (react app inside it) and server folder ( node is here ).
- To make it shorter: how to redirect user from /login (react router dom route ) route to another react route ?

Comment: You can handle redirection at router level too. Here is a general idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979202/2873538 Also here is an example: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow of authentication.

Comment: In `useEffect` use `history.push('/you_new_route')`once the user is successfully logged in. `history` is defined as `const history = useHistory()` from `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use Redirect through React Router DOM like this

Import the Redirect

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Declare redirect state as null inside your constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { redirect: null };
}
```

Inside your render() method include a check for redirects

```
if (this.state.redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={this.state.redirect}/>
}
```

Then where you are carrying out your POST request to login the user, upon successful verification - set the state.redirect to the path of the component you wish to redirect to.

```
this.setState({redirect:"/dashboard"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to use https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#history.push in the successful login case. Make sure you persist whatever is necessary client-side before doing this, so the app doesn't throw the user back on the login page.

Comment: How to know if user email and password is there in my database if i'm on the client side ( in react ) ?

Comment: @OmarAbouassy When the app loads you send a request that establishes wether the user is already authenticated. It's like being allowed back into a night club because you have a stamp on your forearm. The bouncer knows you already logged in before and lets you pass.

Answer (score -1):

For class Component:

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...

after the function that performed the operation:

this.props.history.push("/")

...

export default withRouter(example);

For function components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516422/14445061

Comment: So, to make redirection I need to use history object. But how to know if user email and password is there in my database if i'm on the client side ( in react ) ? I mean how to know if it's successful/unsuccessful login ?

Comment: You don't need withRouter, that's only for components that need to be aware of route changes. In the "successful login" case we don't care about that. It's enough to import push directly.