# history.push() doesn't work in a js file where I don't have a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm learning React and I want to use the history.push("/dashboard") but it doesnt work.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { GET_ERRORS, GET_PROJECT, GET_PROJECTS } from "./types";

export const createProject = (project, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/project", project);

    history.push("/dashboard");
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: err.response.data,
    });
  }
};

export const getProjects = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/project/all");
  dispatch({
    type: GET_PROJECTS,
    payload: res.data,
  });
};

export const getProject = (id, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/project/${id}`);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROJECT,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    history.push("/dashboard");
  }
};
```

My problem with the history.push is in getProject not in the createProject

Here is the code where I use the createProject function

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getProject, createProject } from "../../actions/projectActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import classnames from "classnames";

class UpdateProject extends Component {
  //set state
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      id: "",
      projectName: "",
      projectIdentifier: "",
      description: "",
      start_date: "",
      end_date: "",
      errors: {},
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }

    const {
      id,
      projectName,
      projectIdentifier,
      description,
      start_date,
      end_date,
    } = nextProps.project;

    this.setState({
      id,
      projectName,
      projectIdentifier,
      description,
      start_date,
      end_date,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.getProject(id, this.props.history);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const updateProject = {
      id: this.state.id,
      projectName: this.state.projectName,
      projectIdentifier: this.state.projectIdentifier,
      description: this.state.description,
      start_date: this.state.start_date,
      end_date: this.state.end_date,
    };

    this.props.createProject(updateProject, this.props.history);
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="project">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h5 className="display-4 text-center">Update Project form</h5>
              <hr />
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                      "is-invalid": errors.projectName,
                    })}
                    placeholder="Project Name"
                    name="projectName"
                    value={this.state.projectName}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                  {errors.projectName && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.projectName}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                      "is-invalid": errors.projectIdentifier,
                    })}
                    placeholder="Unique Project ID"
                    name="projectIdentifier"
                    value={this.state.projectIdentifier}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    disabled
                  />
                  {errors.projectIdentifier && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                      {errors.projectIdentifier}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <textarea
                    className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                      "is-invalid": errors.description,
                    })}
                    placeholder="Project Description"
                    name="description"
                    value={this.state.description}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  ></textarea>
                  {errors.description && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.description}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <h6>Start Date</h6>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    className="form-control form-control-lg"
                    name="start_date"
                    value={this.state.start_date}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <h6>Estimated End Date</h6>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    className="form-control form-control-lg"
                    name="end_date"
                    value={this.state.end_date}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </div>

                <input
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

UpdateProject.propTypes = {
  getProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  createProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  project: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  project: state.project.project,
  errors: state.errors,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProject, createProject })(
  UpdateProject
);
```

I saw solutions where I need to use withRouter but I don't have a class in this js file so I don't  know if this helps for me

I hope somebody can help me

Comment: So where is createProject used, can you share the component?

Comment: Also what router is used?

Comment: What is `history.push`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516300/how-to-use-in-reactjs-functional-component-history-push

Comment: I updated my question with the component and my problem with the history.push() is in the getProject

Comment: @Keith I saw it in a tutorial. Maybe it is bad and I should not use it..

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in `UpdateProject` class component , it is not receiving history object as a prop , so what you need to do is , you need to wrap the `UpdateProject` component with withRouter hoc what it will do is it will pass `history` and `location` props to the component , you can do it like below

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'

//...

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { getProject, createProject })(
  UpdateProject
))
```

or you can use a compose function from redux and pass it like below

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import {compose} from 'redux'

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps,({ getProject, createProject }))
)(UpdateProject);
```

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getProject, createProject } from "../../actions/projectActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import classnames from "classnames";

class UpdateProject extends Component {
  //set state
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      id: "",
      projectName: "",
      projectIdentifier: "",
      description: "",
      start_date: "",
      end_date: "",
      errors: {},
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }

    const {
      id,
      projectName,
      projectIdentifier,
      description,
      start_date,
      end_date,
    } = nextProps.project;

    this.setState({
      id,
      projectName,
      projectIdentifier,
      description,
      start_date,
      end_date,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    console.log(this.props.history,"check that you are getting history prop")
    this.props.getProject(id, this.props.history);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const updateProject = {
      id: this.state.id,
      projectName: this.state.projectName,
      projectIdentifier: this.state.projectIdentifier,
      description: this.state.description,
      start_date: this.state.start_date,
      end_date: this.state.end_date,
    };

    this.props.createProject(updateProject, this.props.history);
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="project">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h5 className="display-4 text-center">Update Project form</h5>
              <hr />
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                      "is-invalid": errors.projectName,
                    })}
                    placeholder="Project Name"
                    name="projectName"
                    value={this.state.projectName}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                  {errors.projectName && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.projectName}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                      "is-invalid": errors.projectIdentifier,
                    })}
                    placeholder="Unique Project ID"
                    name="projectIdentifier"
                    value={this.state.projectIdentifier}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    disabled
                  />
                  {errors.projectIdentifier && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                      {errors.projectIdentifier}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <textarea
                    className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                      "is-invalid": errors.description,
                    })}
                    placeholder="Project Description"
                    name="description"
                    value={this.state.description}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  ></textarea>
                  {errors.description && (
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.description}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
                <h6>Start Date</h6>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    className="form-control form-control-lg"
                    name="start_date"
                    value={this.state.start_date}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <h6>Estimated End Date</h6>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    className="form-control form-control-lg"
                    name="end_date"
                    value={this.state.end_date}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </div>

                <input
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

UpdateProject.propTypes = {
  getProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  createProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  project: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  project: state.project.project,
  errors: state.errors,
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { getProject, createProject })(
  UpdateProject
));
```

Comment: The createProject works fine, my problem is with the getProject

Comment: Got the issue , I have updated by code , please check it if it helps

Comment: I tried both 2 solution but I still have the error..